# Froala Editor bold button does not work as expected

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, froala, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building a web app that allows users to write their own html pages using the Froala editor integrated on my website.

The editor works really well and provides a great degree of control as well but, there is a small problem I am facing with the **bold** button. If you highlight some text inside the editor and click on the bold button, in the editor the text does become bold but in the corresponding html which is generated has a simple `<strong>` tag around it. Now when you load that html on a browser when it is delivered via a link or any other service, it does not show up as bold unless we write some css for it.

What I would like to know is:

1. Is this the correct behaviour?
2. Is there any fix or option that we need to control on Froala to make
   it look bold?

Apart from writing custom css for it, if there are any options please let me know.

You can check out the said behaviour on one of the demo pages they have: [Froala Demo](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v2-0/examples/sticky-toolbar/)

Thanks in Advance!

PS: Let me know if you guys need code samples from my end, I have not done anything(custom) apart from the samples available on their website.

Comment: Are you using some css reset style ? `strong` should show as bold by default.

Comment: Found the issue, @GabrielePetrioli there is some library I imported , it has this fonts.scss is over writing bold to font-weight: 500